# Vim: need to press Enter after opening a file before it will actually open

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

Recently, Vim started behaving strangely.

Whenever I open a file with Vim in the terminal, I see the line that is normally at the bottom of vim:

```
"<filename>" [dos] ###L, ###C
```

But instead of the buffer being displayed above, the screen is blank.
When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, however, the buffer displays normally.

What did I change to make Vim behave this way when I open files, and how can I change it back?

[Here's my `.vimrc`.](https://gist.github.com/4053482)

---

I'm on a Mac, running OS X 10.8, using Vim 7.3.

Comment: Please post your `.vimrc` file. We have no idea what you could have changed without seeing it.

Comment: Yeah maybe post a gist or pastie link. Have you installed any plugins lately or updated your .vimrc?

Comment: Good call. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/4053482

Comment: Do a quick check to test whether the .vimrc is related to the issue by restarting vim in a default state with:  ```vim -u DEFAULTS -U NONE -i NONE```.  If opening the file still displays a blank screen then the problem is not the .vimrc.  If a file opens and displays properly then you know to debug the .vimrc.